# Linux serial port direct in the background

Tags: serial-port, port, tty, tee

I'm trying to redirect one serial port to another serial port in Linux command line, but put it in the background so it doesn't interfere with my regular use of the command line.
I am issuing this:

cat /dev/ttyS0 > /dev/ttyS1 &

and the second enter key i press it kills the process and it all exits. I tried using tee, cat, tail, everything i could think of but as soon as I put it in the background (&), it just won't work.

Any ideas how this can be done or this can be done? Should I wrote a C program that does this for me?

Thanks